# I can get the value of a form select input to a validator but i just cant seem to pass the data into the database

Tags: laravel

i can get the value of every other input in the form into validator and so is the select option values too but while the other request data pass along to the database the select option value always turns up empty. Here is my code...thanks in advance

Here is the Register Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use App\Admin;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the login form.
     * 
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function showRegisterForm()
    {
        return view('admin.auth.register',[
            'title' => 'Create A New Administrator On This Page.',
            'registerRoute' => 'admin.register',
        ]);
    }



    /**
     * Create a new admin instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\Admin
     */
    public function create(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate(request(),[
            'firstname' => 'required|string|max:255|alpha|min:2',
            'lastname' => 'required|string|max:255|alpha|min:2',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:admins',
            'privilege' => 'required|numeric',
            'consent' => 'required',
        ]);

        $newAdminGeneratedPassword = unique_random('admins', 'password', 10);
        $admin = Admin::Create([
            'firstname' => $request['firstname'],
            'lastname' => $request['lastname'],
            'email' => $request['email'],
            'privilege' => $request['privilege'],
            'password' => Hash::make($newAdminGeneratedPassword),
        ]);

        return redirect()->to('/admin/register')->with('admincreated', 'New Administrator with Privileges Created');

    }
}
```

Here is the HTML FORM

```
@extends('layouts.app')


@section('title')
OneNaira&copy;&nbsp;Register A New OneNaira Initiative Administrator
@endsection




@section('content')
<!--HOME PAGE NAVBAR-->
<div class="ui top attached pink inverted secondary menu">
    <div class="ui container">
        <div class="header item">One&#8358;aira</div>
        <a class="toc item">
            <i class="sidebar icon"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="right menu" id="large_menu">
            <a href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}" class="item">Create A New Agent</a>
            <a href="" class="item">Manage Existing Agents</a>
            <a href="" class="item">Manage Agent Payments</a>
            <a href="{{ route('admin.register') }}" class="active item">Create A New Administrator</a>
            <a href="" class="item">Manage Existing Administrators</a>
            <a href="{{ route('admin.logout') }}" class="item">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--SIDEBAR MENU-->
<div class="ui inverted vertical sidebar menu">
    <a href="{{ route('admin.dashboard') }}" class="item">Create A New Agent</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Manage Existing Agents</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Manage Agent Payments</a>
    <a href="{{ route('admin.register') }}" class="active yellow item">Create A New Administrator</a>
    <a href="" class="item">Manage Existing Administrators</a>
    <a href="{{ route('admin.logout') }}" class="item">Sign Out</a>
</div>


 <!--PAGE CONTAINER-->  
 <div class="ui stackable grid" id="page_container">
    <div class="sixteen wide column">
        <div class="ui container">

            @if(session('admincreated'))
                <div class="ui floating info message">
                    <i class="close icon"></i>
                    {{ session('admincreated') }}
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="ui raised very padded segment">
                <div class="ui dividing pink header">
                    One&#8358;aira
                    <div class="sub header">{{ $title }}</div>
                </div>


                <form action="{{ route($registerRoute) }}" class="ui form" method="POST">

                {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="field">
                        <label>{{ __('Name:') }}</label>
                        <div class="two fields">
                            <div class="field">
                                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First" value="{{ old('firstname') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('firstname'))
                                    <div class="ui negative message">
                                        <p>
                                        {{ $errors->first('firstname') }}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                @endif

                            </div>
                            <div class="field">
                                <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last" value="{{ old('lastname') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('lastname'))
                                    <div class="ui negative message">
                                        <p>
                                        {{ $errors->first('lastname') }}
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                @endif

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label>{{ __('E-mail:') }}</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Please Enter A Valid Email Address" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                        @if ($errors->has('email'))
                            <div class="ui negative message">
                                <p>
                                {{ $errors->first('email') }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        @endif

                    </div>
                    <div class="disabled field">
                        <label>{{ __('Password:') }}</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="This Password will be Automatically Generated" required value="1234567890">

                        @if ($errors->has('password'))
                            <div class="ui negative message">
                                <p>
                                {{ $errors->first('password') }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        @endif

                    </div>
                    <div class="disabled field">
                        <label>{{ __('Verify Password:') }}</label>
                        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" id="password-confirm" placeholder="This Password will be Automatically Generated" required value="1234567890">
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label>{{ __('Privilege:') }}</label>
                        <select class="ui dropdown" name="privilege">
                            <option value="">Privilege</option>
                            <option value="2">Administrator</option>
                            <option value="1">Super Administrator</option>
                            <option value="0">Root Administrator</option>
                        </select>

                        @if ($errors->has('privilege'))
                            <div class="ui negative message">
                                <p>
                                {{ $errors->first('privilege') }}
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        @endif

                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <div class="ui checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" name="consent" id="consent" tabindex="0" class="hidden" required>
                            <label>{{ __('I Consent To Creating This Administrator and Granting the Delegated Privileges') }}</label>

                            @if ($errors->has('consent'))
                                <div class="ui negative message">
                                    <p>
                                    {{ $errors->first('consent') }}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            @endif

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="ui pink button" type="submit">{{ __('Create Administrator') }}</button>
                </form>
                <div class="ui divider"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="push-50"></div>
@endsection




@section('footer')
<!--FOOTER-->
<div class="ui stackable pink inverted secondary pointing menu" id="footer">
    <div class="ui container">
        <a class="item">© OneNaira, 2019.</a>
        <div class="right menu">
            <a class="item">
                <script>
                    var todaysDate = new Date();
                    document.write(todaysDate);
                </script>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Here is my Routes

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use App\Grant;
use App\Slot;
use App\Events\ProgressUpdaterEvent;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

//Index Route
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('index');
});

//Auth Verify Locking Routes
Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

//Page Routes
Route::get('/checkgrants', 'GrantController@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard')->middleware('auth')->middleware('verified');
Route::view('/accountsettings', 'accountsettings')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/wallet', 'WalletController@index')->middleware('auth');
Route::view('/faq', 'faq');
Route::view('/policy', 'policy');

// Log Out Routes
Route::get('/logout', function(){Auth::logout(); return Redirect::to("/login")->with('message', 'You have been successfully logged out');});



//Grant Search Route
Route::any('/searchgrant', function() {
    $q = Input::get ('grant_id');
    $grant = Grant::where('gid', $q)->get();
    if (count($grant) > 0)
    {
        return view('checkgrants')->withDetails($grant)->withQuery($q);
    }
    else {
        return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Grant Not Found !. It might be found the next time you try');
    }
});


//Route User Edit and Update Route
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');

//Route For SLOT Reservation
Route::resource('slots', 'SlotController');

// Laravel 5.1.17 and above for paystack
Route::post('/pay', 'PaymentController@redirectToGateway')->name('pay'); 
Route::get('/payment/callback', 'PaymentController@handleGatewayCallback');

//Route For Pusher Testing
Route::get('event', function(){
    $slotallcount = Slot::all()->count();
    event(new ProgressUpdaterEvent($slotallcount));
});

// Admin Grouped Routes
Route::prefix('/admin')->name('admin.')->namespace('Admin')->group(function(){
    Route::namespace('Auth')->group(function(){
        //Login Routes
        Route::get('/login','LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
        Route::post('/login','LoginController@login');
        Route::get('/logout','LoginController@logout')->name('logout');

        //Register Routes
        Route::get('/register', 'RegisterController@showRegisterForm')->name('register');
        Route::post('/register', 'RegisterController@create');

        //Forgot Password Routes
        Route::get('/password/reset','ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
        Route::post('/password/email','ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.email');

        //Reset Password Routes
        Route::get('/password/reset/{token}','ResetPasswordController@showResetForm')->name('password.reset');
        Route::post('/password/reset','ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.update');

    });

    //Route For Administrator Dashboard Points Directly To Create Agent Page
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');


});
```

and here is my migrations please help

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateAdminsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('admins', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('firstname', 100);
            $table->string('lastname', 100);
            $table->smallInteger('privilege');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 255);
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('admins');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add "privilege" field in $fillable array of Model